# CAPL measure time from sleep to wakeup LIN

Tags: capl, canoe

I am using CANoe 10 with LIN bus.
I want to  measure the time from sleep command to wakeup(the first frame from the slave).
Here is a sample of the code that I made soo far in a test node

```
    void MainTest ()
    {
    linGotoSleep();
    testWaitForTimeout(1000);
    linWakeup(1, 1, 300);
    

    ReceiveLinFrame(Status);
    ReceiveLinFrame(Status);
    }
void ReceiveLinFrame(linFrame *rxFrame)
{
    int ret = 0;
    rxFrame.rtr = 1;
    output(rxFrame);
    rxFrame.rtr = 0;

    ret = TestWaitForMessage(rxFrame.id, 500);

    if(ret==0)
    {
        TestStepFail("Receiving Message", "No answer received for:0x%02X",rxFrame.id);
    }
    else
    {
        TestGetWaitEventMsgData(rxFrame);
        TestStepPass("Receiving Message", "Answer received for:0x%02X",rxFrame.id);
    }
}
```

[image]

I don't understand why the first frame is not visible in trace.

Here is the report
[image]

Also, why needs to be  a wait time from sleep to wakeup in order to see the frames in trace window?

Comment: Which _first frame_ are you missing? From what I can see, the frame from the salve arrives at `5.299820` which is `0.506591` seconds after the wakeup. The first `testWaitForMessage` misses that frame by 6 ms.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your time. I am missing the first  ReceiveLinFrame(Status); line. Also I have a problem with the wait time from  linGotoSleep(); to linWakeup(). If i don't give enough time (more than 100 ms) the actuator is not responding

Comment: The first `testWaitForMessage` runs into a timeout. You can see that in the test report at timestamp 5.292211: _No answer received_. As I said, the first frame seen on the bus arrives at 5.299820 and is captured by the second `testWaitForMessage`.